# How to prove this limit result?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory, game-theory, bayes-theorem

I'm quite sure the following is true, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Fix some $p\in(0,1)$. For any $p'\in[0,1]$, there exists sequences $\{x_n,y_n\}_{n=0}^\infty \subset (0,1)$ s.t. $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_np}{x_n p + y_n(1-p) } =p'$$

**Motivation for this question:** in broad strokes, proving the above illustrates [Sequential Equilibria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_equilibrium#:%7E:text=Sequential%20equilibrium%20is%20a%20refinement,for%20each%20of%20the%20players.) and [Perfect Bayesian Equilibria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_Bayesian_equilibrium) are equivalent in simple [signaling games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signaling_game). (Apologies if this is still cryptic. A "proper" explanation would require a much, much, longer post.)

Comment: Given any $p\in(0,1/2]$ WLOG, it's trivial to prove the result for $p'\in (p, 1-p)$, which is doable by constant sequences. Do you have some intuition for other cases?

Comment: This is trivial. You can in fact make the ratio equal to $p'$ for all $n$

Comment: Oh.... duh.  Thanks, both!